# Clicking asp:menu item causes postback. How can I stop this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, postback

I've got the following navigation menu on my page:

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink" id="NavDiv" style="margin:0 auto; display: table;">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="NavUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Menu ID="NavMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" width="703px"
                BackColor="#CC3300" EnableViewState="false">
                <Items> 
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/OLDMain.aspx?page=1" Text="1" Selectable="true" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/OLDMain.aspx?page=2" Text="2" Selectable="true" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/OLDMain.aspx?page=3" Text="3" Selectable="true" />
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/OLDMain.aspx?page=4" Text="4" Selectable="true" />
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

This is used for pagination, so I can switch between pages.  The problem is, when I click anything in this menu, I get a full postback.  I don't want it to postback, because it's reloading my default dropdown values every time.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent a full postback when a menu item is clicked?

Comment: it's not postback, it's new page request

Comment: Is there any way to prevent it, or even trap for it?

Comment: Why would you do that? I mean navigation is meant to redirect, redirect means requesting new page

Comment: I just edited to give a few actual items.  This navigation menu is actually used for paging.  And it works fine in a paging sense, it's just that it resets all my dropdowns that I use for filtering, and then the paging gets based off the default dataset instead of the filtered dataset.

Comment: AMAIK it can't be done. work around here could be saving dropdown values in session or alike but it is really really dirty way.